# How to enable the "From SharePoint" link when inserting a link in a blog post?

Tags: document-library, blog

When I create a new post in a Blog website, I would like to insert documents by picking them directly from my SharePoint libraries.

Actually there is an option for that but it appears disabled even I am logged with a full control account.

Here is a screenshot of the menu:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a thread about it on [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/sharepoint2010general/thread/04890968-3fdc-4658-ab6c-c7421d73788a)

The essence from the thread:

- You'll need to activate SharePoint Server Publishing
- It is not available in enhanced rich text but it is in Publishing HTML. Change your column type to Publishing html and it will work

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that is almost as good.

Just select "From Address" and enter the URL of the SharePoint Site, and like magic, you can browse all your SharePoint libraries and select the image you want.

The only downside is you have to enter the site URL (or have it saved as a mapped drive), and also upload the image to another library as it doesn't know the image is already in SharePoint.

Comment: does not worked for me sp 2010

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 it works, when you activate the Site SharePoint Server Publishing Feature. Then the select function for an Image with "From SharePoint" is available and no more greyed out. Then you can choose Images from SharePoint within rhich text fields in InfoPath browser enabled forms.